# EM waves in Anisotropic media: source of the index ellipsoid equation

Tags: optics, waves

I'm reading Amnon Yariv & Pochi Yeh's Photonics book, and trying to follow the derivation in section 1.7. I understood rather well the Fresnel's equation of wave normals, quoted here for convenience:

$$ \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{s_x^2}{n^2-n_x^2} + \frac{s_y^2}{n^2-n_y^2} + \frac{s_z^2}{n^2-n_z^2}$$

Where $n$ is determined by this equation, and $n_x,n_y,n_z$ are given by the material's principal axes $\varepsilon$ matrix.

I don't understand the purpose of the index ellipsoid equation:

$$ \frac{D_x^2}{\varepsilon_x} + \frac{D_y^2}{\varepsilon_y} + \frac{D_y^2}{\varepsilon_y} = 2 U_e $$

Where did it came from? Did it came directly from Fresnel's equation of wave normals?

Moreover, I don't understand what is the physical meaning of the substitution $\mathbf{D} \rightarrow \mathbf{r}\cdot\sqrt{2\varepsilon_0 U_e}$ - I mean, what is the physical meaning of all of these points $\mathbf{r}$ in space that satisfy this equality?